# Asking opinions about the architecture you have designed?

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to ask for opinions and corrections on the very specific architecture you've designed for a game, posting class diagrams and other detailed information?

I was thinking that perhaps questions that are too specific may not be very useful for the community.

If that is so, what other sites do you suggest for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is close, but the FAQ says **no** "Higher-level architecture and design of software systems." But they **do** allow "Best practices and design pattern usage in your code."

So no architecture questions, but you *could* post specific sections of code for review - and might get refactoring or architectural suggestions in return. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll defer to the [faq](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

> **avoid** asking subjective questions where …
>
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

Comment: But what about "I've used this design pattern here and here, and this class does that and that. Is it a smart approach?". The problem to be solved here is that I have little experience and want to avoid doing silly mistakes.

Comment: Well from my POV you want to make those mistakes since that's how you learn.  From the stackexchange POV, if you aren't "solving a problem" then it isn't the right place for it.  Trying to avoid future problems isn't solving a problem.